# C# Запуск процесса в фоновом режиме

Tags: c#, windows

Необходимо скрытно запускать консольное приложение. (тестирую на cmd)
Использую такой код:

```
    var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"c://cmd.exe",  // Путь к приложению
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

В обычном режиме (UseShellExecute = true) консольное приложение запускается, но в скрытном режиме нет. Это сразу видно по диспетчеру задач. Может кто знает в чем проблема и какие способы решения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В диспетчере задач ваш процесс в любом случае будет видно, этого не избежать.
Но можно скрыть консоль.
Попробуйте так:

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    prc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    prc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe";
    prc.Start();
    prc.CloseMainWindow();
```