# Не запускается файл .exe

Tags: c#

В приложении WPF есть необходимость открыть файл с расширением exe в фоновом режиме.Открыл диспетчер задач во время нажатия кнопки, crypto_parser.exe там не оказался.Открывая файл с помощью чистого без ничего `Process.Start()` файл открывается.Код из этой программы я нашел в ответе на этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/660169/198316).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Crypto_Tracker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            prc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            prc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Trecker\crypto_parser.exe";
            prc.Start();
            prc.CloseMainWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Нашел в сети этот вариант:

```
var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Trecker\crypto_parser.exe",  // Путь к приложению
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Эффект тот же что и от предыдущего.Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Comment: В первом случае все вполне логично и следует из документации [CloseMainWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx). Я понятия не имею что это за парсер такой, но вы точно уверены что ему не нужны ни какие дополнительные параметры для работы? А если его нужно просто запустить, то зачем вы закрываете его окно? Что будет если его просто запустить двойным кликом?

Comment: @rdorn это лишь кусочек программы.Сама программа по моей идеи  возможно покажущейся вам и другим пользователям  не самой лучшей т.к. я предпологаю можно было сделать проще.crypto_parser.exe является прасером сайта написанном на языке Python который записывает данные с сайта в csv файл.А программа на c# открывает crypto_parse.exe тем самым запуская процесс парсинга.В дальнейшем она считывает данные и csv файла дальше не буду рассказывать т.к вам для ответа на вопрос или к иным действиям касательно этого вопроса не к чему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("crypto_parser.exe");
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Trecker";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.Start();
```

Это строчки кода позволили мне сделать то что я и хотел. Скрипт, видимо, использовал относительные пути, так что когда запуск производился из другого места (=> рабочая папка также менялась) скрипт малость ломался.Тем самым я ответил на свой вопрос.

Comment: + за самостоятельность =) А разобрались в чем собственно проблема была? Если да, то стоит описать подробнее

Comment: @rdorn у ТС была проблема с `WorkingDirectory`. Скрипт, видимо, использовал относительные пути, так что когда запуск производился из другого места (=> рабочая папка также менялась) скрипт малость ломался

Comment: @Kir_Antipov это мне понятно, просто тонко намекнул на необходимость писать ответ так, чтобы он был понятен другим. Видимо слишком тонко...